# C# .NET WPF Application hangs randomly (WgxConnection_ShouldForceSoftwareForGraphicsStreamClient)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I wrote a WPF .NET Application (.NET 4.5) using the following libraries:

- System.Windows.Interactivity.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll
- GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform.dll
- GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.dll
- GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll

I use 2 Timers:

- `System.Threading.DispatcherTimer` (ticks every 200ms)

  - Just sets a DateTime property, that is bound to a label, to DateTime.Now.
- `System.Timers.Timer` (ticks every second)

  - Set focus to a textbox, requests data from a webservice (in a async Task)
  - Update a ICollectionView bound to a Datagrid (using  `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`)

The application runs on ~ 50 Windows 7 machines (from 7am to 5pm) without any problems.

On only 1 Windows 7 machine it just randomly freezes with a high CPU usage and the only active thread: `WgxConnection_ShouldForceSoftwareForGraphicsStreamClient`

There are no entries in the windows event log and there is no user event that triggers this.

I can not find anything about this `WgxConnection...` Does anybody have any ideas?

EDIT:

Just found the snippet "UnsafeNativeMethods.WgxConnection_ShouldForceSoftwareForGraphicsStreamClient();" in MediaSystem.cs:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/windows/Media/MediaSystem.cs

--> wpfgfx_v0400.dll

Maybe "RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;" can change the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to identify problem without seeing code sample.

Here is few points, that i can think of

1. Revisit code and see if there is any blocking code. Note that
   because you are using timers, you must use thread safe list implementation (ConcurrentQueue,ConcurrentStack,ConcurrentBag).
2. If it is working well on all desktops except one then see if that PC has some different GPU. There might be some incompatibility between WPF and available GPU drivers.
3. Try to use Dispatcher timer instead of System.Timers.Timer.

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatch timer could be used to do the job of the system timer as well.

Just stick an if modulus statement in checking `if(timer % 1000 == 0)` and then call your async data request functions.

In regards to the main problem, find out what is different on the one computer, is it using the same graphics card, how about driver?

Are you using a zoom or other graphical effects anywhere in the program?

My thoughts are that some sort of driver issue is occurring on that machine where it tries to enact an effect and the graphics on that system are not capable, and for some reason software rendering cannot be enabled it then gets stuck trying to do this effect in an endless loop.

Comment: I haven't found a difference between this and other PC's yet, regarding the GPU.

I don't use any graphic effects except a "IsIndeterminate=true ProgressBar" that is shown, while background work is done.

I set the frame rate to 20 due to better performance (default 60fps): Timeline.DesiredFrameRateProperty.OverrideMetadata(... 


I wonder if HW rendering is actually needed in my case. There would be the possibility to deactivate it, setting:
ProcessRenderMode.

Comment: The program runs every day without interruption, it is startet every day in the morning though. The problem described, arises just every few days...

Comment: Are you using the timer for fps or an actual graphics card command?

Comment: I don't use the timer for that. I use this command:          Timeline.DesiredFrameRateProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Timeline),
               new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { DefaultValue = 20 });

Comment: Timeline is an animation effect, this combined with a minor driver corruption could be causing your issue. 

I am assuming that when you checked the pc you also checked the version of the GPU driver and the model of the graphics chipset/card?

Remove the framerate property (or use other methods to acheive the same thing) and see what happens.